# Comparing in data in excel

Tags: excel

Anybody knows how to compare data in two columns in excel?
This is the conditions, if `column R = Column S` result should be `PASSED`, else if `column R - Column S > 1`, result is `FAILED` and if the two column's difference is `0.01` only, it should return `Rounding Off Error`.

I've already tried this one but is not working well :

```
=IF(ROUND(R5,2)=ROUND(S5,2),"PASS",IF(ROUND(R5,2)>ROUND(S5,2),"Rounding Off Error",
IF(ROUND(S5,2) > ROUND(R5,2), "Rounding Off Error","FAIL")))
```

In this conditions,  `-100.71 - 0.00` and `100 - 0.00` it should return `FAIL`. The conditions I've done only works when this condition is met `-100.71 - 0.00`, it returns `FAILED`. But in this one `100 - 0.00`, it returns `Rounding Off Error`. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(ROUND(R5,2)=ROUND(S5,2),"PASS",IF(ABS(ROUND(R5,2)-ROUND(S5,2))<=.01,"Rounding Off Error","FAIL"))
```

Though you may want to also put in a condition when they are both empty.  Because two empty cells are equal to each other and will return "PASS".

To deal with that add another if at the beginning:

```
=IF(AND(R5="",S5=""),"",IF(ROUND(R5,2)=ROUND(S5,2),"PASS",IF(ROUND(R5,2)-ROUND(S5,2)<=.01,"Rounding Off Error","FAIL")))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, it's not working when it met the conditions if the two columns has a `0.01` difference

Comment: Thanks it works! But you do have any idea to reverse the condition or making an `OR` condition? like in this: if `IF(ROUND(R5,2)-ROUND(S5,2)<=.01` then hoe to make an or to reverse it like: `IF(ROUND(S5,2)-ROUND(R5,2)<=.01` ?

Comment: @ramedju The `ABS()` takes care of that, it makes it absolute. so ABS(100-99) is the same as ABS(99-100) both are 1.  It is already in the formula.

Comment: But why is it that it returns fail to this : `2998.00` and `2997.99` ?
Thanks!

Comment: @ramedju did you try it?  Did it do what I said it would? It is the nature of Absolute. `2998.00 - 2997.99 = .01` and `2997.99 - 2998.00 = -.01`  Absolute removes the negative if there is one so `ABS(.01) = ABS(-.01) =.01`.  This is done in the formula.  It is a mathematical definition.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it, but it is not working well. Thanks!

Comment: condition `2998.00 - 2997.99` returns `FAIL`. Why? I haven't really figured out any solutions to this anymore . Thanks!

Comment: I will look at it in the morning.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @Scott :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ramedju Are you sure you have the formula in the correct rows? It works for me see edit.